# Python: communication between "faraway" classes on the same call chain

Tags: python, class

I have this `start.py`:

```
# start.py

class Start:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    def run(self):
        # some code
```

Executing its `run()` method will at some point invoke the `put_item(obj)` method in `moduleX.py`:

```
# moduleX.py

def put_item(obj):
    # what should I write here
```

`run()` is NOT the direct caller of `put_item(obj)`. In fact, from `run()` to `put_item(obj)` the execution is quite complex and involves a lot of other invocations.

My problem is, when `put_item(obj)` is called, can I directly add the value of `obj` back to `mylist` in the class `Start`? For example:

```
s = Start()
# suppose during this execution, put_item(obj) has been 
# invoked 3 times, with obj equals to 1, 2, 3 each time
s.run() 
print(s.mylist) # I want it to be [1,2,3]
```

**UPDATE**:

1. From `run()` to `put_item(obj)` the execution involves heavy usages of 3rd-party modules and function calls that I have no control over. In other words, the execution inbetween `run()` to `put_item(obj)` is like a blackbox to me, and this execution leads to the value of `obj` that I'm interested in.
2. `obj` is consumed in `put_item(obj)` in `moduleX.py`, which is also a 3rd-party module. `put_item(obj)` originally has GUI code that displays `obj` in a fancy way. However, I want to modify its original behavior such that I can add `obj` to `mylist` in class `Start` and use `mylist` later in my own way.
3. Therefore, I cannot pass `Start` reference along the call chain to `put_item` since I don't know the call chain and I simply cannot modify it. Also, I cannot change the method signatures in `moduleX.py` otherwise I'll break the original API. What I can change is the content of `put_item(obj)` and the `start.py`.

Comment: your description of your problem is incomplete and confusing. Can you add more info?

Comment: `put_item` should be a method on your `Start` class

Comment: @Dalek I've updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `put_item` return the item you want to put in your instance:

```
def put_item():
    # some code
    return 42

class Start:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    def run(self):
        # some code
        self.mylist.append(put_item())

s = Start()
s.run()
print(s.mylist)
```

Prints:

```
[42]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you will have to propagate a reference to your `Start` object's list down the call stack to `put_item()`.  Your `Start` object can then add items to the list.  It does not have to know or care that the object it is being passed is in the `Start`.  It can just blindly add them.

For example ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/8Y6MBI)):

```
class Start:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    def run(self):
        foo(self.mylist)
        print(self.mylist)

def foo(listRef):
    bar(listRef)

def bar(listRef):
    someItem = "Hello, World!"
    put_item(listRef, someItem)

def put_item(listRef, obj):
    listRef.append(obj)

x = Start()
x.run()
```

Of course, you'll get the appropriate runtime error if the thing you pass to foo turns out not to be a list.